# It is possible to tweak matplotlib style after it is set?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams.update({
    "axes.grid" : True,
    "grid.linestyle": "dotted",
    "grid.linewidth": 1/2,
})
```

and I have grid lines in all plots automatically.

Alas, these settings are overwritten by [`matplotlib.style.use`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/style_api.html#matplotlib.style.use), so I have to define

```
def mpl_use_style(style):
    plt.style.use(style)
    mpl.rcParams.update({
        "axes.grid" : True,
        "grid.linestyle": "dotted",
        "grid.linewidth": 1/2,
    })
```

and use `mpl_use_style` instead.

Is there a better way?